# Synchronizing Hazelcast IMap with the database postgres

Tags: postgresql, hazelcast, cdc, hazelcast-jet

I am using hazelcast jet to capture database changes. I have a pipline which catch database changes and update IMap:

```java
    Pipeline pipeline(StreamSource<ChangeRecord> theDataBase, IMap<Long, String> myMap) {
        var pipeline = Pipeline.create();
        pipeline.readFrom(theDataBase)
                .withoutTimestamps()
                .writeTo(CdcSinks.map(myMap, 
                        record -> Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(record.key()).toMap().get("id").toString()), 
                        record -> record.value().toJson()));
        return pipeline;
    }
```

And I would like to do reverse synchronization, i.e. make a request to update a record in the database when the map changes.

I tried this by adding a second pipeline:

```java
    Pipeline pipelineReversed(IMap<Long, String> myMap) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
        p.readFrom(Sources.mapJournal(myMap, START_FROM_CURRENT))
                .withoutTimestamps()
                .writeTo(Sinks.jdbc("%some update query%", () -> {
                    BaseDataSource dataSource = new PGXADataSource();
                    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db");
                    dataSource.setUser("postgres");
                    dataSource.setPassword("postgres");
                    dataSource.setDatabaseName("my_db");
                    return dataSource;
                }, (stmt, record) -> {
                    // fill query params and execute                         
                }));
        return p;
    }
```

However I get recursion, the map and database endlessly update each other. Can I avoid recursion in this approach? Or maybe there are other tools and best practices?

Comment: I was thinking of using a mapstore instead of a second pipeline (piplineReversed). But then the data in the IMap is updated twice.

Comment: Add a column indicating source of update to DB. For example source : FromIMap or source : fromUser. Then you can filter CDC changes and get rid of the recursion

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [`MapStoreAdapter`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/MapStoreAdapter.html) and I question whether you need to be using Jet at all to fetch database changes, but then again I don't know the architecture of your system. I'd read more here:

https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/mapstore/working-with-external-data